# Reflex muscular activity in three months old fetus

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-physiology, development

> At the end of the third month, reflex activity can be evoked in
>   aborted fetuses, indicating muscular activity

This quote is from **Langman's Medical Embriology**.
Have I misunderstood it or it is really talking about muscular reflexes in *aborted fetuses*?

Do we have any video proof or something like that?

How does it happen and why?

Why do we need a muscular reflex during prenatal life?